# Features disappear from Leaflet after zooming in

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-studio

I have a Mapbox studio template which already looks the way I want it to, but when I put it in a Leaflet app, after I zoom in past level 17, a lot of the features disappear.  Zooming in inside Mapbox studio, everything looks fine. It's only in the Mapbox app. Another peculiar thing is that generating the static image also makes the features disappear.

All the layers have visibility from zoom 0-22, so I don't know what the problem is.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be Mapbox starting to glitch out after importing a GeoJSON file I uploaded as a new layer.

I'm not sure if the GeoJSON file was incorrectly formatted, but as soon as I added the GeoJSON file as a layer, this problem started happening.

I ended up just rendering the polygons from this GeoJSON file in Leaflet, and enjoying a better behavior from Mapbox without the GeoJSON file.