# Displaying selected layers depending on zoom in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

It looks like I found the problem between the `document.querySelecto`r and `map.on('zoomend')` function.

I was going to set the zoom level for switching off some layers, what has been raised here:

[Leaflet making features gone when zoom out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340223/leaflet-making-features-gone-when-zoom-out)

although there is a clash with the event `.addEventListener` function in my code.

In the result, when I switch off the layer, it's gone only for temporary zoom level.

When I change the zoom level it appears again, even when remains switched off on the sidebar (see image).

The code looks like:

```
    document.querySelector("input[name=cf]").addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked) map.addLayer(job)
              else map.removeLayer(job)
            })

   document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked) map.addLayer(job2)
              else map.removeLayer(job2)
            })

    document.querySelector("input[name=bt]").addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked) map.addLayer(job3)
              else map.removeLayer(job3)
            })
```

and the part, which is responsible for specified zoom level for dissappearance

```
  map.on('zoomend', function() {
if (map.getZoom() <7){
        map.removeLayer(job);
}
if (map.getZoom() <7){
        map.removeLayer(job2);
}
if (map.getZoom() <7){
        map.removeLayer(job3);
}
else {
        map.addLayer(job);
        map.addLayer(job2);
        map.addLayer(job3);
    }
  });
```

Is it possible to combine these code together, making the layer invisible when scrolling between all zoom levels set in the `map.on('zoomend' function` ?

[image]

Comment: Your `zoomend` handling function does not seem correct. Whenever zoom level is under 7 and zoom level changes, it is trying to remove layers even when they were removed before. And whanever zoom is 7 or greater and zoom level changes, it's adding the same layers again and again

Comment: So what should my zoomend look like?
I tried sth like this:
map.on.document.querySelector("input[name=cf]").addEventListener('zoomend','change', function() {
if (map.getZoom() <7){
    map.removeLayer(job);
 }
 else if (this.checked) map.addLayer(job)
 else map.removeLayer(job)
});

Comment: I ried also sth like this:
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() <6){
            map.removeLayer(job);
    }else{
  map.addLayer(job);
  }
 if (map.getZoom() <7){                //zoom level condition for Virgin Media
            map.removeLayer(job2);
  }else if (this.checked) map.addLayer(job2) 
   else {map.removeLayer(job2) 
   }
 if (map.getZoom() <8){
            map.removeLayer(job3);
    }else{
  map.addLayer(job3);
  }
});
but layers are gone, console says nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to remove layer, you have to check if layer is currently added to the map with `map.hasLayer` method. When trying to add layer you have to check if layer is selected for display and if it's not currently added to the map.

Your `zoomend` function could then look something like this:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
  if (map.getZoom() < 7){
    if (map.hasLayer(job)) map.removeLayer(job);
    if (map.hasLayer(job2)) map.removeLayer(job2);
    if (map.hasLayer(job3)) map.removeLayer(job3);
  }
  else {
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=cf]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job)) map.addLayer(job);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=vm]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job2)) map.addLayer(job2);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=bt]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job3)) map.addLayer(job3);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you for the hint! I didn't take the map.haslayer into account. Thank you so much